# Watch whole folder for SASS changes with Grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am trying to watch an entire folder for sass changes..

The directory is follows:

creatives/lp/folder/style.scss

creatives/lp/folder1/style.scss

And here is my grunt file

```
sass: {
      dist: {
        files: {  
          'creatives/lp/**/test.css' : 'creatives/lp/**/test.scss'
        },
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
        },
      }
    },
```

Grunt is able to see sass changes but writes out the compiled CSS to:

creatives/lp/**/style.css

The CSS should be saved in the same folder as the source SCSS file...

Answer (score 0):

your question is not so clear for me 
- if you want multiple files to compile to one file with grunt you can make the files as array format

```
dist: {
  files: [{
    src: ['creatives/lp/folder/*.scss'],
    dest: 'creatives/lp/folder/style.css',
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the css file should be created in the same folder as scss file, you can use the following snippet.

```
 sass: {                             
        dist: {                          
            options: {                       
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'creatives',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest:'creatives',
                ext:'.css'
            }]
        }
    }
```

I hope it solves your problem.